# Redbean O/RM store "date" as varchar(255)?

Tags: php, mysql, orm, redbean

From this code:

```
$toolbox = RedBean_Setup::kickstartDev("mysql:*****************");

$r = $toolbox->getRedBean();

$test = $r->dispense("test");
$test->nom = 'Test #1';
$test->date = '2010-07-08';
$test->date_deux = '08/07/2010';
$test->num = 5;

$id = $r->store( $test );
```

I get this SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nom` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `num` tinyint(3) unsigned default NULL,
  `date_deux` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `nom`, `date`, `num`, `date_deux`) VALUES
(1, 'Test #1', '2010-07-08', NULL, NULL),
(2, 'Test #1', '2010-07-08', 5, NULL),
(3, 'Test #1', '2010-07-08', 5, '08/07/2010'),
(4, 'Test #1', '2010-07-08', 5, '08/07/2010'),
(5, 'Test #1', '2010-07-08', 5, '08/07/2010');
```

is there a special way to use `date` with RedBean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found this: http://groups.google.com/group/redbeanorm/browse_thread/thread/6961ac635e6886f6

> The Optimizer will now convert columns
>   with datetime values to 
>   datetimefields. If a different value
>   is inserted the column will be 
>   reverted by OODB in fluid mode.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you need to be very specific in the format for a datetime column.  For instance, the following code should provide a date/time column:

`$mysqldate = date("Y-m-d", $your_date); // for date column` 
OR
`$mysqldatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $your_date_time); // for datetime column`

Specifically, "Y-m-d" for date, and "Y-m-d H:i:s" for datetime, are the formats RedBean is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use time() or change the column type after freezing the DB.

Comment: but it will be stored as an integer, and it will be harder to make SQL based on date comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The Standard Optimizer handles DateTime columns. You can check it out here: http://redbeanphp.com/#/Plugins (almost at the end of the page)