# Are there any Micro-ORMs written for PHP

Tags: php, orm

Is there a Micro-ORM similar to Dapper, PetaPoco, or Massive ... but for PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: @simshaun that Q is about ORMs; micro-ORMs are kinda a different category

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I consider http://redbeanphp.com/ to be a very lightweight ORM, not sure if it's comparable to the ones you listed.

Comment: How well does RedBeanPHP handle dates now? Is there clear examples on how to avoid problems mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212917/redbean-o-rm-store-date-as-varchar255

Comment: It's designed to handle them differently from how Sirber describes in the linked question: http://www.redbeanphp.com/extra/special_types

Comment: Re: special types - Any thoughts on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495750

Answer (score 7):

You can check out [Idiorm & Paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/).

Comment: Idiorm is just one 2k line php file.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO ORM is not only right way, for many reasons. May be some DAL could be enough in many cases. Try e.g. simple and smart query builder [FluentPDO](https://github.com/lichtner/fluentpdo)